# How to properly link / gather lots of VCC and GND?

Tags: power, relay, raspberry-pi, vcc

I have a system where I have quite a few sensors (more than 10). The signal pins are connected to the Raspberry Pi - but the sensor VCC and GND are not since there's not enough 5V pins.

I was thinking about adding an external power-source - a 12 V 20 Ah battery and then add a stepdown from 12 to 5 V. But between the 5 V stepdown module and all the VCC and GND - how do I connect these in the most professional manner? I've thought about a multi channel relay and connect the pins here and also connect the stepdown that's connected to the battery here (as power source).

How to connect multiple VCC and GND to a battery in a good way?

Here's my "schematics" -> my question is about the purple square connected to the battery. The lines with a red circle and green square are connected to all modules as VCC and GND
[image]

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE! Please draw a schematic or block diagram of what you have and need to solve.

Comment: Google: "Bus Bar"

Comment: @Majenko thanks - just what i was looking for :)